# Is ID field of a Google Calendar Event base32hex encoded?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

Using Google API explorer, I found out the `id` of a specific event in my calendar:

```
_6tlnaqrle5p6cpb4dhmj4phpehomip3975p68qj569gmaqj669knadrjelo68eb161gmcdjgcdh6os1kdtk3cpblcso66dhmehim6qr7csr6e
```

I read an explanation here:

[Events  |  Google Calendar  |  Google for Developers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource-representations)

> characters allowed in the ID are those used in base32hex encoding, i.e. lowercase letters a-v and digits 0-9, see section 3.1.2 in RFC2938

So, I see that the underscore appearing in the obtained `id` doesn't match that specification.

What's the issue here ? Is the `id` encoded using a different system ?